# sharing intellij/Eclipse settings with other authors?

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea

What is the recommended way to share IntelliJ/Eclipse settings with other team members?

Ideally I would like for things like "build configurations" to be shared at the same place that the code is, since I do not view those as too different from my pom or Makefile.

But at the same time I do not think colors and other personal settings should be shared (nor cause annoyances such as keeping a dirty file in `git` working copy)

Answer (score 0):

For Eclipse, you store the supported settings into your project and share the project through a source control system, like `git`, like everything else. Usually those are set up through the project's Property pages.